# How to use Plotly/Dash (Python) completely offline?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Working with **Dash 0.22.0** and **Python 2.7.12**. Plotly is 3.1.0 but not used in the following example.

I am trying to create a minimal app that should work completely offline.

Instead of loading from remote `dash_html_components/bundle.js`, `dash_renderer/bundle.js`, `react.min.js` and `react-dom.min.js`, I put their local copies in `/assets/js`. I want to tell Dash to use only the local copies of these files.

I read [Assets files & index customizations #286](https://github.com/plotly/dash/pull/286) and if I understood well the following example should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-    
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

# default values
app.config.assets_folder = 'assets'     # The path to the assets folder.
app.config.include_asset_files = True   # Include the files in the asset folder
app.config.assets_external_path = ""    # The external prefix if serve_locally == False
app.config.assets_url_path = '/assets'  # the local url prefix ie `/assets/*.js`

app.layout = html.Div(
    [html.H1("this is a test")]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

HTML source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Dash</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/materialize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/material-icons/material-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="react-entry-point">
        <div class="_dash-loading">
            Loading...
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
         <script id="_dash-config" type="application/json"<{"requests_pathname_prefix": "/", "url_base_pathname": "/"}</script>
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.4.2/dist/react.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.4.2/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/dash-html-components@0.11.0/dash_html_components/bundle.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/dash_html_components_0.11.0/bundle.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/react_15.4.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/react_15.4.2/react.min.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/dash_renderer_0.13.0/bundle.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/materialize_1.0.0.rc2/materialize.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/js/materialize_1.0.0.rc2/materialize.min.js"></script>
         <script src="/assets/material-icons/iconjar-map.js"></script>
         <script src="https://unpkg.com/dash-renderer@0.13.0/dash_renderer/bundle.js"></script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, my local js files are loaded from `/assets`, but it keeps loading the same files from `https://unpkg.com/...`

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps it's something hard coded? If so, you might submit an issue or pull request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like I missed a simpler solution. I put it here if somebody is trying to to the same.

**Don't include a local copy** of dash libraries (`dash_html_components/bundle.js`, `dash_renderer/bundle.js`, `react.min.js` and `react-dom.min.js`) in `/assets`.

Use `/assets` only for js and css files not related to Dash and React. In my case `materialize.js`, `iconjar-map.js` and their respective CSS.

Adding instead:

```
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
```

will do the trick.

Code is now:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

# default values
app.css.config.serve_locally = True
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config.assets_folder = 'assets'     # The path to the assets folder.
app.config.include_asset_files = True   # Include the files in the asset folder
app.config.assets_external_path = ""    # The external prefix if serve_locally == False
app.config.assets_url_path = '/assets'  # the local url prefix ie `/assets/*.js`

app.layout = html.Div(
    [ html.H1("This is a test")]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

and the resulting html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>Dash</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/materialize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/material-icons/material-icons.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="react-entry-point">
            <div class="_dash-loading">
                Loading...
            </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
            <script id="_dash-config" type="application/json">{"requests_pathname_prefix": "/", "url_base_pathname": "/"}</script>
            <script src="/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react@15.4.2.min.js?v=0.13.0"></script>
            <script src="/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/react-dom@15.4.2.min.js?v=0.13.0"></script>
            <script src="/_dash-component-suites/dash_html_components/bundle.js?v=0.11.0"></script>
            <script src="/assets/js/materialize_1.0.0.rc2/materialize.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/assets/material-icons/iconjar-map.js"></script>
            <script src="/_dash-component-suites/dash_renderer/bundle.js?v=0.13.0"></script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Alex. I am using this tutorial, and the dash template provided here: `view-source:https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-vanguard-report` is loading a bunch of 3rd party CCS and JS. Do you have any ideas of which CCS and JS should I download to my `/assets` dir?

Comment: Hi @weefwefwqg3. Alas I didn't work on the project for some months now and I cannot help you. Sorry.